# Synonym for all-hands meeting

Tags: synonyms

I want a synonym for *all-hands meeting*. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is 'all-hands meeting'...?

Comment: A plenary session?

Comment: *[Whole shebang](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whole_shebang#Noun) meeting*? (Or for brevity, just  *shebang*, as in  “Everyone's invited to the shebang”)

Comment: Can you specify more? What do _you_ mean by 'all-hands meeting'?

Comment: *General meeting?* *Public meeting?* Do you mean a meeting that everyone attends, or that everyone is commanded to intend, or everyone is allowed to intend? What is the purpose of the meeting? How often is it held? Is it regular or convened on an extraordinary basis? I suspect that *all-hands meeting* is jargon in your workplace but might have a specific meaning to you that doesn't apply elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an all-hands meeting is different than a regular one by requiring everyone to attend, you can use **mandatory meeting** as a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

Usually companies use "Staff Meeting," "Employee Meeting," "Company Meeting," or my company also just uses "Quarterly Meeting" (4 times a year) with "All-Hands Meeting."

I can't think of any more ways to label a company meeting with going into specific titles like "quarterly."

Comment: +1 for "company meeting", which implies all hands. (The other terms are often used in more restrictive contexts: a staff meeting could be just for one dept, or for "staff" as opposed to "partners" in a law firm, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could call it a Town Hall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).